# How to save file on server side using applet?

Tags: java

Sir/Madam,
     I have design an application using java-applet in that i want to save pdf file on server location i.e http://www.mywebsite/myfolder/ . On local side it will run successfuly but actualy on server side it will not work.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do file uploads via a Java applet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050964/how-to-do-file-uploads-via-a-java-applet)

Comment: Any context regarding the problem might be much more helpful than a generic problem defination

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you would like the applet to store the file on the server. That is obviously not possible because the applet runs on the client. The option I can think of, is to implement an HTTP Post from the applet to the server and handle it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: applets run on client side so they save nothing on server.

Longer answer: that applet will have to communicate somehow with a server side-application. I.e. like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050964/how-to-do-file-uploads-via-a-java-applet) SO Q&A.

A question on tech stack: Is it really necessary to use applet? It's obsolete technology. Can't you use a [jnlp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/running.html) rich client application? Or a simple webapp?